# How can I use @CookieValue in a Parameter Object Class?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, cookies, parameter-object

Is it possible to put @CookieValue in a parameter object?  I can't seem to get this to work
whats is missing?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Response getAllActiveUsers(CookieParameters parameterObject) {

  return getUserImpl.getAllActiveUsers(parameterObject.userToken,
                 parameterObject.loggedInUserId);
}
```

Here is the parameter object class.

```
public class CookieParameters {
public String userToken;
public String loggedInUserId;

public CookieParameter(
    @CookieValue(value = "Token", defaultValue = "") final String userToken,
    @CookieValue(value = "LoggedInUserId", defaultValue = "") final String  loggedInUserId) {
    this.userToken = userToken;
    this.loggedInUserId = loggedInUserId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is possible.  From my understanding, the `@CookieValue` can only be put on the parameters of a handler method.  I think you would have to grab the `@CookieValue` and put them in your parameter object manually.